# How do I delete a Section?

Tags: templating

I created a section with the wrong slug. I am now trying to delete the section to start over, or supply a new slug, but I can't do neither. How can I delete this section, or supply a new slug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete an Section, go to Settings -> Sections, then click the fain't, almost invisible icon to the right of the offending Section name.